# Font rendering different on Mac firefox

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype, text-rendering, webpage-rendering

Hello I'm trying to develop a site using a custom font.

However Firefox is rendering the custom font a lot different from Chrome (Chrome is rendering it 'correctly' in my eyes) anyone got any idea on making the firefox'es around the World render the font like Chrome?

The font is:

> > reddit directory » Local

in the top bar of:

http://redditdirectory.com/54/Local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: Had to specifically set the font-weight to **100** a.k.a **thinner** using da CSS